# Spark seems to misatch with Hive ... What can I do?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Currently I have deployed the hadoop-based data warehouse and I want to use Spark as the processing engine and Hive as its metastore:

- Hadoop: 2.9.0
- Hive: 2.3.3
- Spark: 2.4.8

In the official documentation of Spark 2.4, we can edit (spark.sql.hive.metastore.version) to make it match with Hive metastore version.

Unfortunately, when I do like this:

```
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder \

... .appName("MySparkApp") \

... .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hadoop-master:9083") \

... .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://hadoop-master:9001/sparksql-dw/") \

... .enableHiveSupport() \

... .getOrCreate()

>>> spark.sql("show databases").show()
```

It shows like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/hadoop_cluster/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco

return f(*a, **kw)

File "/usr/local/hadoop_cluster/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.sql.

: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':

at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:206)

at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)

at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:104)

at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$3.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:133)

at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$3.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:133)

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listDatabases(SessionCatalog.scala:247)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(databases.scala:44)

at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ShowDatabasesCommand.run(databases.scala:44)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)

at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)

at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:194)

at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3369)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)

at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3368)

at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)

at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)

at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:643)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)

at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)

at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)

at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)

at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)

at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:203)

... 35 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalog.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/catalog/ExternalCatalog;)V

at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:56)

... 40 more

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "/usr/local/hadoop_cluster/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql

return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)

File "/usr/local/hadoop_cluster/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__

File "/usr/local/hadoop_cluster/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco

raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':"
```

What should I do?